# WooCommerce 'product_type_selector' filter showing my custom type but saving as a simple product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add custom product type through a plugin by using `product_type_selector` filter, although my product is showing on the select but whenever I save the product choosing my product type it shows 'simple' product if I do `var_dump( $product->product_type )` on `single-product.php` template.

I do not know what am I doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: MY CuSTOM PRODUCT TYPE
 * @since       1.0
 */

/**
* Required functions
*/
function product_code_loader() {
  class WC_Product_Custom_Product_Type extends WC_Product {
    public function __construct( $product ) {
      $this->product_type = 'my_custom_product_type';
      parent::__construct( $product );
      add_filter( 'product_type_selector', array( $this, 'add_my_custom_product_type_to_select' ) );
    }

    function add_my_custom_product_type_to_select( $product_types ) {
      $product_types['my_custom_product_type'] = __( 'My Custom Product Type', 'my_custom_product_type' );
      return $product_types;
    }
  }
  new WC_Product_Custom_Product_Type(null);
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'product_code_loader');
```

Comment: Any code would be appreciated to help you !

Comment: @Benoti I have updated my question with sample code. I have tried hooking up my class with plugins_loaded action and extending the class with WC_Product but have no effect what so ever.

Comment: Why not use : new Custom_Product_type::init() instead of code_event _manager ?

Comment: @Benoti Yeah I meant that. But it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new product type, you need to extend the class WC_Product.

```
class WC_Product_New_Product_type extends WC_Product{

}
```

You can read [this tutorial](http://jeroensormani.com/adding-a-custom-woocommerce-product-type/) to see how it works. This example will show you, how add the new product type to the select, hide panel when new product type is selected...

Here is how I did it by extending the WC_Product class.

```
class WC_Product_Online_Service_Product extends WC_Product {
    public function __construct( $product ) {

        $this->product_type = 'online_service_product';

        parent::__construct( $product );

        // actions & filters follow
    }
 new WC_Product_Online_Service_Product(null); // parameter null but not empty.
```

As you can see the __construct() has a parameter and I don't use static function (really don't know if you can). Try to add it to your init()

Comment: Like I said I've already tried this but it also does not help.

Comment: I am so sorry to say I've tried everything you said but I do not know what am I doing wrong here WooCommerce does not agree that it is a custom product type it just shows it as a simple product type. I have updated my question with full source code of my simple plugin.

Comment: Your problem is that you want to run a class that stands in a function ! Your class is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Funny but looks like problem for me is having dash or underscore.
I struggled with same problem right now and find out that: 'custom_product' would not work but 'custom' would save.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adjusting the classname + product_type string? I've fixed my issues making it compatible.

Eg: `WC_Product_Custom_Product_Type` should receive a `custom_product_type` instead of `my_custom_product_type`, or in your example modifying it to `WC_Product_My_Custom_Product_Type`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. in my case it was because of namespaces of my woocommerce product class. woocommerce dose not support it by default. so I fixed it by using this filter to add my class_name custom logic

> woocommerce_product_class

for example I had "WC_Product_Gift" class in  "example" namespace

```
namespace example

class WC_Product_Gift extends WP_Product{
  //content...
}
```

that should give me "example/WC_Product_Gift" as class name but woocommerce was returning only the "WC_Product_Gift" part. I used this code to fix the problem:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_class', 'foo');

public function foo(string $class){
    if($class == 'WC_Product_Gift'){
        return 'example/WC_Product_Gift';
    }
    return $class;
}
```

you can test the result by calling this method:

```
WC_Product_Factory::get_product_classname( <product_id>, 'gift')
```

This is a simular question to this one:
[Woocommerce (3.0) Product type won't save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583218/woocommerce-3-0-product-type-wont-save)