# Woocommerce (3.0) Product type won't save

Tags: woocommerce

Recently updated Woocommerce to 3.0 and after that i having problem to save my custom product type that i have created.

This is what the code look like now.

```
function register_xxxxxx_product_type() {

    class WC_Product_package extends WC_Product {
    public function __construct( $product ) {
        $this->product_type = 'xxxxxx';
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'register_xxxxxxx_product_type' );

function add_xxxxxx_package_product( $types ){
   // Key should be exactly the same as in the class
   $types[ 'xxxxxx' ] = __( 'xxxxxx' );
   $types[ 'xxxxxx' ] = __( 'xxxxxx' );
   $types[ 'xxxxxx' ] = __( 'xxxxxx' );
return $types;

}

add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_xxxx_package_product' );
```

are there anyone who have solved this?

Thanks!

UPDATE

Now my code look like this

```
function register_xxxxxx_product_type() {

class WC_Product_package extends WC_Product {

    public $product_type = 'NameOfType';
    public function __construct( $product ) {
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }
  }
}

 add_action( 'init', 'register_xxxxxx_product_type' );


  function add_xxxxxx_package_product( $types ){
 // Key should be exactly the same as in the class
 $types[ 'xxxxxx_package' ] = __( 'xxxxxx Paket' );
 $types[ 'xxxxxx_parts' ] = __( 'xxxxxx Tillbehör' );
 $types[ 'xxxxxx_service' ] = __( 'xxxxxx Tillvalstjänster' );
 return $types;

 }

 add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_xxxxxx_package_product' );


 function woocommerce_product_class( $classname, $product_type ) {

 if ( $product_type == 'NameOfType' ) { // notice the checking here.
$classname = 'WC_Product_package';
 }

 return $classname;
 }

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', 'woocommerce_product_class', 10, 2 );
```

But is not working. What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE #2

Okey, this is how it looks like now.

```
function register_daniel_product_type() {

class WC_Product_package extends WC_Product {

    public $product_type = 'daniel';
    public function __construct( $product ) {
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }
  }
}


add_action( 'init', 'register_daniel_product_type' );


function add_daniel_package_product( $types ){

// Key should be exactly the same as in the class

$types[ 'daniel_package' ] = __( 'Daniel Paket' );
$types[ 'daniel_parts' ] = __( 'Daniel Tillbehör' );
$types[ 'daniel_service' ] = __( 'Daniel Tillvalstjänster' );
return $types;
}

add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_daniel_package_product' );

function woocommerce_product_class( $classname, $product_type ) {

if ( $product_type == 'daniel_package' ) { // notice the checking here.
    $classname = 'WC_Product_package';
}
return $classname;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', 'woocommerce_product_class', 10, 2 );
```

Sorry that i am slow but would you please give it a try one more time to explain it for me.

Thanks!!

Comment: no, `$product_type == 'NameOfType'` should relate to product_type_selector `$type` variable.. and not to your created class... please check my answer again... you're doing it wrong..

Comment: Okey, i have change it now but still not working...

Comment: then you're not doing it as how I did in my answer below.

Comment: can you please see my update #2. Thanks

Comment: ok try changing `public $product_type = 'daniel';` to `public $product_type = 'daniel_package';`

Comment: with that you'll be able to select and save `Daniel Paket`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this is how to do it.

first make sure your class that extends to `WC_Product` is hooked on `init`.

```
function register_xxxxxx_product_type() {

    class WC_Product_package extends WC_Product {

        public $product_type = 'xxxxxx';
        public function __construct( $product ) {
            parent::__construct( $product );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_xxxxxx_product_type' );
```

then add your product type.

```
function add_xxxx_package_product( $types ){
   // Key should be exactly the same as in the class
   $types[ 'xxxxxx' ] = __( 'xxxxxx' );
return $types;

}

add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_xxxx_package_product' );
```

then use your created class for your product type.
If you don't have this, then you'll be stuck on `WC_Product_Simple`.

```
function woocommerce_product_class( $classname, $product_type ) {

    if ( $product_type == 'xxxxxx' ) { // notice the checking here.
        $classname = 'WC_Product_package';
    }

    return $classname;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', 'woocommerce_product_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: @Reigel Perfect, this just got me out of a huge slump. One question though, what's that '10, 2' for at the end of the filter?

Comment: @ChristianGröber, 10 is default priority, 2 is the number of parameter expected in function `'woocommerce_product_class'`, that is in `function woocommerce_product_class( $classname, $product_type )`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this worked.

```
class WC_Product_Exam_Training extends WC_Product_Variable {
```

But i had a small issue.
When i selected the new product_type, and saved it,
WC would somehow turn in back into a 'variable' product,
instead of the custom type "exam_training"

After some 'debugging' i found the issue:

In the **WC_Product_Variable** class there is a function:

```
 /**
 * Get internal type.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_type(): string {
    return 'variable';
}
```

This function needs to be present in the new class too, and set the new 'type' in there too.
THEN WC will save it as the correct product type

So in the new class i got:

```
...
 public string $product_type = WC_Product_Types::WC_TYPE_EXAM;

/**
 * Get internal type.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_type(): string {
    return $this->product_type;
}
...
```

hope this helps the future devs on this topic